# Converting PayPal IPN script to Stripe Webhooks

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am looking to get away from PayPal IPN, and move towards Stripe.

The point of the script is to send out an email to a customer every time I receive a payment over a certain amount.

The code I have written so far is. For some reason it isn't working.

```
Stripe::setApiKey("XXX");

// Retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body);

}
mail "expresspoints@outlook.com";
$to = $customer->email;
if (($event_json->type == 'charge.succeeded') and ($event_json->livemode == 'true') and 
($event_json->amount>4))
{
```

So the point of the script is, all succesful payments, which are done in live mode, and are larger than 4 will receive an email. The rest of the script is just a normal email.

I thinkthere is an error with:

```
}
mail "expresspoints@outlook.com";
$to = $customer->email;
if (($event_json->type == 'charge.succeeded') and ($event_json->livemode == 'true') and        ($event_json->amount>4))
{
```

Comment: ***Is*** there something wrong with your script? Does it work?

Comment: Add it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

What response do you get when testing your webhook?

Do check the value of 'allow_url_include' in your php.ini. It should be 'On'. Default is 'Off'.